# the value of 'current_user.is_authenticated' is always False in Template

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, flask, flask-login

I create login for user in home page if user click on login then the login page is display there user enter email id and password if email id and password is correct then I redirect user to home page. Now In home page I replace login to user name and logout. For that I user `current_user.is_authenticated` in template file if it is true then the user name and logout is display but It always false in template I dont know why. I have config.json and there I define params so don't worry about that. Here is my python code.

```
local_server=True

app=Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key='supper-secret-key'

login_manager=LoginManager(app)
login_manager.session_protection="strong"


class Users(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__='users'
    user_id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

    def is_active(self):
        return True
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return self._authenticated
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Users:{self.first_name}>'
    def get_id(self):
        return (self.user_id)
    def set_password(self,password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
    def check_password(self,password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    try:
        return db.session.query(Users).get(id)
    except:
        return None

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html", params=params)

@app.route("/login", methods=['POST','GET'])
def login_post():
    print("before login",current_user.is_authenticated)    #False
    email=request.form.get('email')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    remember=True if request.form.get('remember') else False
    user=Users.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    user.check_password(password)
    if not user:
        flash('Please check your login details and try again.', 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    login_user(user,remember=remember,force=True)
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        print(current_user.first_name)  # user name is properly printed
    flash('Login Successful','success')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

@app.route("/register")
def register():
    return render_template('register.html',params=params)

@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register_post():
    first_name = request.form.get('fname')
    last_name = request.form.get('lname')
    email = request.form.get('email')
    password= request.form.get('password')
    password2=request.form.get('cpassword')
    if (password!=password2):
        flash('Password must be same','danger')
        return render_template('register.html', params=params)
    users=Users.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if users:
        flash('Email address already exists','warning')
        return redirect(url_for('register'))
    new_user=Users(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,email=email)
    new_user.set_password(password)
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash('You were logged out','warning')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

I think everything is ok in python code. And here is the code of my template file

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}     <!-- here current_user.is_authenticted is false -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <img src="static/img/userlogo.png" width="30" height="30" class="rounded-circle" alt="">
          Hey {{ current_user.first_name }}
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" style="padding-left: 8px;">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark" role="button" aria-pressed="true" href="/logout">Logout</a>
      </li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="nav-item" style="padding-left: 8px;">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark" role="button" aria-pressed="true" href="/login">Login</a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation you can read:

> To make implementing a user class easier, you can inherit from UserMixin, which provides default implementations for all of these properties and methods.

You inherit von `UserMixin` so you do not need to implement all these methods - maybe that is your problem.

https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/main/docs/index.rst#your-user-class

e.g. my (simplified) User class looks like this:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):  # type: ignore
    ...
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'<User {self.email}>'
```

No authentication helper needed at all!